# How to make last word of a string output to the last line in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am currently utilizing regex, docx, and PIL in order to extract text from a document, read from keyword to keyword, and output the extracted strings onto images that I create within a loop in the code. I currently have everything working, the only thing holding me back right now is that I cannot get the very last 4 characters of the string to output on the last line of the output image. The following is the code that's pertinent to this problem:

```
for match in find_matches(text=docText, keywords=("responsive", "detecting", "providing")):
    match_words = match.split(" ")
    match = " ".join(match_words[:-4]) + "\n" + match_words[-4]
    W, H = 300, 300
    base = Image.new('RGB', (W, H), (255, 255, 255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()

    current_h, pad = 50, 5

    for key in textwrap.wrap(match, width=50):
        line = key.encode('utf-8')
        w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
        draw.text(((W - w) / 2, current_h), line, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
        current_h += h + pad
    for count, matches in enumerate(match):
        base.save(f'{match[-4:]}.png')
        bbox = ImageOps.invert(base).getbbox()
        trim = base.crop(bbox)
        patent = ImageOps.expand(trim, border=10, fill=(255, 255, 255))
        patent = ImageOps.expand(patent, border=3, fill=(0, 0, 0))
        patent.save(f'{match[-4:]}.png')
```

From this code, I'm showing 2 sample outputs:

[image]
[image]

What I want to be able to accomplish is shown in the following image:

[image]

That is, have the last 4 characters of the string (ex: 248C and 249C) be output on the very last line of the image, with nothing else accompanying it.
Currently, the following lines don't seem to be having any affect on the outcome of the code, and with out without these lines, the output remains the same:

```
match_words = match.split(" ")
match = " ".join(match_words[:-1]) + "\n" + match_words[-1]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you add a newline and then wrap your string in `textwrap.wrap`. That function is meant for single paragraphs and removes your newline again. Better to separately write the last word outside of the textwrap loop.

Comment: Thanks! Got it from this. Just had to make another for loop.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Rob in the comments, I found that I had to simply create another for loop with a different variable, that being the variable that stored all of the last-line strings, and use that to output on the next line, as shown in the code and the outputs here:

```
for match in find_matches(text=docText, keywords=("responsive", "detecting", "providing")):
    match_words = match.split(" ")
    part = " ".join(match_words[-1:])
    match = " ".join(match_words[:-1])
    W, H = 300, 300
    base = Image.new('RGB', (W, H), (255, 255, 255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()

    current_h, pad = 50, 5

    for key in textwrap.wrap(match, width=50):
        line = key.encode('utf-8')
        w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
        draw.text(((W - w) / 2, current_h), line, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
        current_h += h + pad
    for obj in textwrap.wrap(part, width=50):
        partNum = obj.encode('utf-8')
        w, h = draw.textsize(partNum, font=font)
        draw.text(((W - w) / 2, current_h), obj, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

x="hello world"

print(x[ : -5 : -1])

output:-
dlro

last 4 word of string